# Google sheet create dropdown from some values in column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working with google sheet. I have two sheets named App Catgeory and Directory Category.

App category have two column:-
1. Category Name
2. Is Selectable

In Directory Category i have category selection dropdown which is created from Category Name column of App category sheet.All the values in Category Name column are available in dropdown.
Dropdown is created by this data validation formula:-

```
='App-Category'!$C$2:$C
```

But, I want such Category Name in dropdown which have Is Selectable column value Yes in App category.If Is Selectable column value is No then such category Names are not need to displayed in dropdown.
So, how can i achieve this.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you cannot directly achieve what you are expecting. instead you can have a derived column using a query to get the dropdown values and then use it to populate the drop down.

```
= QUERY('App Catgeory'!A2:B21,"select A where (B = 'yes')")
```